# Codeigniter Auto Responder

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the main library it has the following:

```
 $CI-email-from(AUTORESPONDERS_FROMEMAIL, AUTORESPONDERS_FROMNAME);
```

I have noted throughout the controllers that it uses the following:

```
 /** Send user a course request phone call success email: - sends a BCC to staff **/
                 @$this-autoresponder-send(15, $booking['email_address'], $responder_array['%full_name'], $responder_array, TRUE);
```

I have also noted in the constants file - in the config folder the previous developer has set the following:

```
 define('AUTORESPONDERS_FROMEMAIL', "email@domain.org");
 define('AUTORESPONDERS_FROMNAME', 'Domain');
 define('AUTORESPONDERS', 'ON'); // used for debugging and development to switch autoresponder emails ON or OFF
```

Am I able to do "email@domain.org", "email1@domain.org"?

Comment: Are you talking about the `AUTORESPONDERS_FROMEMAIL`? If yes, then you cannot give multiple comma-separated values since there can only be one 'from' address for an email.

Comment: @xbonez Thank you is there away that I can do a CC?

Comment: You can send it to as many people as you want by using comma separated email addresses for the to-field like this: `"email1@example.com, email2@example.com"`. As mentioned in my previous comment, this doesn't work for the `from` field since there can be only one sender, but you can have as many recipients as you want.